UNI-T UT181A question: what is confidence interval used in the datasheet?
So the question is: https://www.batronix.com/pdf/uni-t/UT181A-Manual-English.pdf
The manual has

So if you are measuring perfect 50 Hz source you have resolution 0.001 Hz the values are in interval from 50 Hz - 0.2% 50 Hz - 0.008 Hz = 49.982 Hz are okay. In practice I can get 49.989 Hz, so it is in spec., in fact it appears it has a constant mistake -0.022 (as the source was 50.001 Hz, also see this https://youtu.be/PjNXbKlr3MI?t=1792) in all modes, so 500 is measured as 499.89 Hz, 5 kHz as 4.9989 kHz, 50 kHz as 49.89 kHz and 500 kHz as 499.89 kHz.
The sigma accuracy does not apply for frequency apparently, as Gnuradio developer clarified. So then the question is for voltage.
I am pretty sure it is 100%. Or at least 99.73%. Unless something really bad happens and the SOC inside the multimeter gives up I cannot see how do you get such low confidense of 1 sigma which is mere ~68%.
Also, how do they measure that interval? Do they decrease the interval until you get needed sigma? What happens if sigma always stays high?
Also what does it mean for military equipment to have more than one sigma? Do they have two datasheet entries, on for 68.27%, 1 sigma and another for 95%?

"everyone assumes": Please give a reference for that. I'm not assuming that. I'm also not assuming 100% of time or 99.73% of time, you'll really need to explain where these numbers came from, Valerij!

@MarcusMüller Everyone assumes Confidence interwall of one sigma (that is 68.27%) unless specified otherwise.

No, they don't. That makes sense for amplitudes of normal variables, and I don't see an indication for that here.

@MarcusMüller Yes, they do. https://www.google.com/search?q=accuracy+of+a+multimeter+confidence+interval Well, the internals of modern multimeters is complex. Indeed, it would make sense that typical statistics doesn't work for them, even if the datasheets say that it does.

you're misinterpreting your search results. Voltage fluctuation under Johnson-Nyquist noise is a normally distributed random variable. Frequency estimation isn't; nothing in the datasheet claims that, that's just you!

@MarcusMüller Okay, but with Voltage I also am very sceptical it is 68.27%.

You already mentioned the key word here, $\sigma$! Because 68,something% of realizations of a normal random variable fall within one standard deviation ($\sigma$) of its mean.

@MarcusMüller Okay, but Military equipment will have more than one sigma accuracy. So why is that not the case with my multimeter?  Intuitively, I would say it is accurate enough or at least 95%.

"military equipment will have more than one sigma accuracy": Uh, I think you're really confused here. I've mentioned that several time now, so maybe you'll really need to read up on normally distributed random variables, and what sigma means in context of these.

@MarcusMüller Is it possible it actually does some form of continuous measurement and the datasheet specifies it for 1 measurement? Of course if you have 68%, you can measure 50 times and see what is most accurate (more than 50% value)

No. That makes no sense. Again, this is really basics of normal variables, and I can't explain that better than a textbook on measurement theory or the wikipedia article on normally distributed variables could. don't speculate – read!

I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the wrong assumption that the measurement of frequency had normally distributed error, and that the accuracy given was the standard deviation of that. Neither is the case, as discussed in the comments.

@MarcusMüller Prove that for this multimeter before voting close

no, this is not about your multimeter. This is just about the fact that the assumptions about distribution do not hold. And they don't – you're the one making the surprising claim that they do, and the absolutely wrong claim that 68% is the right measure for every case. I don't have to prove anything here, your question is really just based on wrong assumptions, and your newest edit really just added total nonsense.

I think you meant to really fundamentally modify your question – make it about "why do 68% of measurements fall into $1\sigma$ of the mean value; but instead, you just added more confusing text to your question that was already based on wrong assumptions. You'll have to remove all the things that aren't relevant to the question you want to ask from the text, please.

@MarcusMüller Please, stop acting this way. You are not helping the OP, and you are being absolutely biased. This is not new from you.

@Brethlosze I edited the question. It should be "nicer" to answer now.

@Brethlosze please, then, go ahead and answer the question. I've really really really tried to help and explain, work with OP to improve their question. The result was that OP added  "what does it mean for military equipment to have more than one sigma?", which frankly, makes no sense on multiple levels. I hope you can appreciate my frustration here, being accused of being unhelpful after spending half an hour trying to help.

@ВалерийЗаподовников thanks for the edit ! That really helps a bit. I'll try to answer.


What is the confidence interval given in the datasheet

The datasheet did not specify a confidence interval! It specifies an accuracy, and that's a different thing.
In this case, what that means is probably that given (a hypothetical) noise-free input, how accurately this device measures the frequency. It measures the frequency accurately with an error less than what's specified in the parentheses, for example a 500 kHz tone would be detected as something between 500 kHz · (1-0.01%) - 5 Hz to 500 kHz · (1+0.01%) + 5Hz, so 499.945 kHz to 500.055 kHz. The actual confidence interval would also need to incorporate precision, which would be a function depening on the noise your signal is exposed to, and not specified in the datasheet.

Also what does it mean for military equipment to have more than one sigma?

It makes no sense to say "for military equipment to have more than one sigma". It makes sense to specify some quality for three sigmas of system noise.
I think you have a misconception on what "sigma" is: \$\sigma\$ is the standard deviation of your measurement, or of a variable derived from that measurement.
So, when I say "this is an error bound that holds true for \$3 \sigma\$", I actually need to specify the nature of the probability distribution that describes the system noise. Now, as you'll find out, under normally-distributed noise, which happens to be a common model for noise happening through thermal effects, the error of a frequency estimator is not normally distributed. In fact, the error will depend on the estimator used, and typically it is quite complicated to derive a probability density function for. So, knowing that something holds true for three sigma tells you very little – unless you know the probability density of the error function. (For a more in-depth discussion of this, I'd have to refer you to the literature on the noise probabilities of FM, and error probabilities of FSK communinicatons. But you'd really need a bit of stochastics to work on that; if you don't mind, I think that would leave the scope of your question.)
And that's exactly where your 68% and 99.7% come from: for a normally distributed variable, around 68% of realizations fall within \$sigma\$ of the mean, and around 99.7% fall within \$3\sigma\$. For other distributions, that is not the case! And that's why it's wrong to assume everyone assumes 68% of measurements fall into \$\sigma\$: we don't assume that! We check our assumptions before we apply the math: only if the measurement noise is normal, then we might say that.
Now, a lot of things behave approximately normal, and then it's fine for everyday usage to assume that 68% of measurements do fall into \$\sigma\$ of the true value (let's ignore biases for a moment). But at \$3\sigma\$, you need something to be very precisely normally distributed for that 99.7% to hold true. And that's not always the case, which is why some precision equipment (I assure you, being military equipment has nothing to do with good equipment, in general), will specify more than just the standard deviation.

Also, how do they measure that interval?

Measure a reference, measure it often with different devices, than do statistics and derive the standard deviation.

"only if the measurement noise is normal, then we might say that." I see. That is too complex for me, but makes sense.

@ВалерийЗаподовников which I've been saying since my second comment under your question, an hour ago

Honestly, this whole thing made me pretty sad. Why have you and Brethlosze been aggressive towards me although I've spent so much time explaining things? I'm going to bed. Have a nice evening, @ВалерийЗаподовников.

It just seems that all you wanted was for me to spend an hour commenting and writing an answer, then you say "oh yeah, I would have to understand that, thanks, but I won't", accept and move on. :(

"What is the confidence interval given in the datasheet" well, I said used. ;) I know it is not given.

Here's an answer:
TLDR Answer:
It depends on your application. I will give you my two answers below, which I parse into the following:

The General answer: It doesn't matter for most
Specific answer: It does matter for the few, usually critical application. In that specific answer, I provide a potential method to obtain your
own confidence interval data to your liking.

First, we'll start with a prelude. Then, with that as context, you can read the general answer (for general technicians and non-critical applications) then specific answers (for more serious applications).
Prelude
First, just to interpret the question as: "How confident is UNI-T, statistically speaking, in its measurements variation to be due to noise across multiple samples for the UT181 device?"
If the question is interpreted corerctly, it's a very interesting question to be answered and can be answered in various ways depending on the application and purpose.
General Answer
Generally speaking, if the product quality is high (from a reputable brand), most electronics technicians don't care (and, the non-engineer electricians generally don't get into such deep electronics considerations as its almost irrelevantly philosophical for them as their goal is to simply get the job done in as little steps as possible without worrying about such abstractions.)
So, in that case, generally speaking, I don't think it matters here as it would in other scientific fields as, due to the nature of electricity, the measurements are made so frequently that, if the measurement value is constant over say a few seconds, the mean sample measurement approaches the value of all possible measurements (sigma, i.e., the population measurement) so the confidence interval can be quite tight for a series of very low-variance readings.
Specific Answer
So, then why does this question matter and is this a good question? Answer follows:
Yes, I do think the question is valid to ask. After considering the general answer above, on the other hand, when high precision and high accuracy DOES matter (depending on your application--say NASA stuff or next-gen military tech), this topic becomes incredibly relevant. Furthermore, what you are asking does matter and is important when you are trying to assess the quality of a product (to which company employees may disagree with and respond negatively here).
That said, in this specific situation, you would focus on the sample rate of your device, and possibly use a fancy benchtop oscilloscope/signal generator to send various known very precise signals to your device. Then see how long it takes, on average, in time (seconds) for you to see a variation from the specifically set signal on your measurement device under test. You can then compute the number of samples using the sampling rate. Then, you can develop a confidence of measurement. If, while sampling, you don't see variation (your measurement device reads 50.00 Hz and matches your signal generator), you start to increase the fineness of the changes to your supply test signal (voltage or current or whatever, in your case, the test frequency of 50 Hz).
Caveat

You need to know statistics and basic electronics to pull this off
and also need the devices. You probably do since you are talking
about confidence intervals.
One issue is the electrical signal produced by the device may vary at
some level of precision from the stated value of that signal (i.e.,
it says 50.000000000 Hz but it's really 49.99999995 Hz. So, your
measurement is only good as your signal generator/oscilloscope.

Hope this helps.

I posted this 1 second ago and I got 1 thumbs down immediately without a comment. I don't think anyone reads that fast. Any reason why please? Is there an administrator/moderator?

this seems to be written by an AI. And it honestly doesn't answer the question: OP is asking about the actual meaning of these numbers, and you are "oh yes, if it's name brand, then you don't care, and otherwise, you need to understand these numbers"

ChatGPT? Nice, man.

You guys are trolling me? Why is EE stack exchange like this?

@MarcusMüller Bo-ho, AI banning rule? Haha

@Валерий Заподовников You probably are trolling which is fine. If u weren't i could simply ask "Can you prove that?" Because I wrote this, meaning you have no evidence.
no evidence, sorry.

you know what, I'm not getting involved in this.

@ Marcus Müller It depends on your application. Maybe ill be more specific....

@PrashanthC I will upvote in 30 seconds, as I am anyway against the rule for banning ChatGPT 4 answers. Yes, it makes sense, no one should care, UNI-T clearly did not. They made multiple mistakes with this multimeter including horrible static electricity protections.

I changed my answer to make it more clear by stating i have two answers as I may not have been clear in my prelude. You have no evidence of that. Please, let's work together and not gatekeep electronics. :)

I'll re-edit the prelude again to include the first bit... Not that AI organizes its answers this way...

Also, I'm flattered by the AI comment but i just don't want to waste anyones time including yours with the debating. I am actually a neuroscience kid--but we deal with electornics equivalents when talking about brain stuff. You can check my linkedin if you like. :)

@PrashanthC By the way if you don't know this multimeter is very scandalous. They locked the firmware for calibration: it is very hard to do. They made a mistake in calculating the frequency, as I mentioned. Finally they incorrectly designed the PCB that does violate the standards that they say they adhered to and this person send UNI-T updated schematics to fix this: https://youtu.be/1kYcY2ogmqo

@ВалерийЗаподовников Actually, I bought a relatively expensive (for me and my hobby) UNI-T device as well :/ I wasn't so happy, partly my fault, because the device they gave had mini-USB interface and I didn't look through all the marketing as it was kinda hodge-podge on AliExpress.  And, I can't find the software or manuals online despite the little fancy paper they give you stating they can? Hopefully, you didn't spend so much like I did :/

@ВалерийЗаподовников If that's the case I'm really sorry. I do know we all want to save a buck--i do especially. That said, to be fair, I really don't know the particular situation. If you don't have a benchtop device, its hard to test it--and you said the firmware is locked... I've emailed them as well just to get some simple software and manual that they said was online--but no response :/
Maybe, their cutting heads cus of recessionary pressures and they said bye-bye to customer service. I don't know.

@PrashanthC I bought it back in 2017, I am very happy with my multimeter: in fact it is better and more accurate than Fluke 289. Even before the calibration, after of course it just destroys it. The problem that the chip inside of it is very hard to calibrate. So as many of you probably know UNI-T UT181A is the best multimeter in its class, better than the same Fluke. Its calibration alone requires firmware manipulation and JTAG and references FLUKE 5522A, P5025 and MC3070 and multimeter Keysight 3458A or KM300HT."

@ВалерийЗаподовников That sounds like a nightmarer. Sorry, I'm not really experienced in this world of testing the world of testing devices haha--i just understand your general thinking and questions here. Good luck! Please follow up in the chat if you get any progress with UNI-T! I'm learning myself.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Im upvoting to compensate for those AIs lol

As you are a good lover for UNI-T equipment (which I personally find too a really price efficient alternative), we cannot left Fluke's team work without any merit.
They give an explanation of what Accuracy Percentage and Digits mean for them (Fluke.com, Why digital multimeter accuracy and precision matter):

Accuracy may also include a specified amount of digits (counts) added to the basic accuracy rating. For example, an accuracy of \$\pm(2\%+2)\$ means that a reading of \$100.0 V\$ on the multimeter can be from \$97.8 V\$ to \$102.2 V\$. Use of a digital multimeter with higher accuracy allows for a great number of applications.

As you can read from your equipment datasheet:

Selected Range: \$0-60 Hz\$

Resolution: \$0.001 Hz\$

Accuracy: \$\pm 0.02%\$ +8 Digits (% Reading + Digits)


Hence, for a \$50.000 Hz\$ signal, with normally 5 significant digits for the UN181A, we should expect a \$\pm50\cdot0.0002 Hz=\pm0.01 Hz\$ error from the % Reading.
The typical format should be 50.000, so the digits accuracy should be taken from this representation of significative digits.
\$\pm1\$ digit means if you have a 50.000 reading, you could expect a reading between 49.999 and 50.001. Thus, 8 digits error means an \$\pm 0.008\$ Hz error when reading 50.000.
Then, you should expect a total error of:
$$
\pm(0.01 + 0.008) Hz = \pm0.018 Hz.
$$
And that is!. We cannot infer anything else outside from this range. Electrical gaussian noise, temperature drifts, sensor drifts, internal compensations, etc. are all in this range and every other further extrapolation, without any specific advice from UNI-T is a side conclusion.
As you could realize, every sigma interpretation would assume a distribution, for which, in this case, do not have information to conclude. Typically we shouldn't too, since the drifts would be more significative.

Yep, calculations are correct. Datasheet even says it is % of the reading, not of the range, so you take 50.000 Hz, not 60 Hz, which is nice. BTW, it also says you need to calibrate every year.

I corrected the typo in my calculation.
